# Space <li> evenly?

Tags: html, css

I have OCD and the following needs to be fixed (the spacing of word's in my navigation bar).

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: Miramonte;
  margin: auto;
}
.navContainer {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
}
nav ul {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 80px;
  display: block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
a:hover {
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
a img {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navContainer">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="art.html"> art </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="download.html"> download </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="home.html">
          <img src="image/symbol.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html"> portfolio </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="product.html"> product </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

All I need is the words to be evenly spread out with the image still intact in the middle like the picture dictates.

Notice how the word art is unevenly spread compared to the right side?

I am the first one to say that I am building my own website and I am new to CSS/HTML scripting.

Appreciate the help,

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code too?

Comment: send Html to solve your problem body

Comment: @Nitheesh GH I posted the html!

Comment: I imagine you want the image to stay in the center? There is **no possible solution** that does all of the following: 1. Spread words "evenly". 2. Center the image. 3. Make the navigation 100% width.

Comment: Please create an image that shows how you want it to look, using the words that you have.

Comment: remove fix-width and put some padding on the left and right in each of every `li` tag. also remove the rules declared on `img`. and put the `vertical-align` base-line on its parent `li` `3rd-child li` to be exact

Comment: @Ron.Basco How are you planning to keep the navigation 100% width then? How will you keep the image in the center?

Comment: This should be closed as it is unclear what OP wants to achieve. As it is stated now, it's just impossible to even create an image that would satisfy the requirements.

Comment: **Since OP refuses to clearly state what they want to achieve I'll have to give this a thumbs down.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: table` / `table-cell` for the list / list items.

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: Miramonte;
  margin: auto;
}

.navContainer {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
}

  nav ul:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
  }

  nav ul {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

    nav ul li {
      text-align: center;
      overflow: visible;
      height: 30px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      float: none;
      width: 1%;
      max-width: 80px;
      display: table-cell;
      position: relative;
    }

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

  a:hover {
    color: #e6e6e6;
  }

  a img {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    right: 5%;
    left: 5%;
  }
```

Comment: How do I un-shrink the image? This worked however the image is now smaller than what I needed.

Comment: @Beelzebub: Give it a pixel-width instead of percentage

Comment: @Beelzebub: This is caused by the 'max-width' rule for the 'nav' element. You should adjust this value according to your desired image width (or remove it all together to spread the 'nav' across device width).

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `float: left` and the `display: block`  from the `nav ul li` CSS selector and then adding

`display: flex;`
`flex-flow: row wrap;`
`justify-content: space-between;`

to the `nav ul` CSS selector will change the display from block to flexible boxes, allowing for the text to be more evenly spread out throughout the entire element

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: Miramonte;
  margin: auto;
}
.navContainer {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
}
nav ul {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  //  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 80px;
  //  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
a:hover {
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
a img {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="art.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; art &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="download.html"> download </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="home.html">
            <img src="image/symbol.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html"> portfolio </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="product.html"> product </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

I added  a few `&nbsp;`  characters around the word `art`  in the link  to give it some spacing to resemble the other links.

`&nbsp;` is how you create whitespace in HTML

Comment: This looks exactly like OP's result. It is not possible to achieve contradictory goals which OP obviously has.

Comment: Actually, get rid of some of the CSS maximums and minimums on the LI elements

Comment: You can also use `justify-content: space-around`

Comment: You have to make the word 'Art' have more letter spacing

Comment: @Beelzebub all finished -- found an even better solution

Comment: @Beelzebub -- `letter-spacing` is the CSS tag to change the letter spacing btw -- i didnt include it because it looked weird with one of the links slightly more spread out than the others -- your best bet is to use whitespace to to perfectly align the nav menu (even tho this is not the best way to do a nav menu (ideally you want to use a series of divs with fixed percentages for width -- since it can then show up properly across all devices  - but thats another question all together

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (with slightly changed markup)?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: Miramonte;
  margin: auto;
}
.navContainer {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul:nth-child(1), nav ul:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul:nth-child(1)::before, nav ul:nth-child(3)::before,
nav ul:nth-child(1)::after, nav ul:nth-child(3)::after{
  content: '';
}
nav ul:nth-child(2) {
  width: 18%;
}
nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 80px;
  display: block;
}
nav ul:nth-child(2) li {
   width: 100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
a:hover {
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
a img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navContainer">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="art.html"> art </a></li>
      <li><a href="download.html"> download </a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html"><img src="http://www.pd4pic.com/images/eye-black-fan-symbol-design-sun-flower-circle.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html"> portfolio </a></li>
      <li><a href="product.html"> product </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just change the `nav` percentage as per your requirement. Also for more accurate results you can add media query.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: Miramonte;
  margin: auto;
}

.navContainer {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 75%;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
}

nav ul:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

nav ul {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: none;
  width: 1%;
  max-width: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  overflow: visible;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover {
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

a img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="art.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; art &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="download.html"> download </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="home.html">
            <img src="image/symbol.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html"> portfolio </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="product.html"> product </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```